# undefined variable $section in the view

Tags: php

i'm trying to do the Forgot Account systeme with the MVC pattern so it works fine

and sent me a mail where i can find the verification code to insert the new

password but i want the views to display a new  depending on a parametre

passed in URL wich is the variable $section but there is an error wich is

undefined variable $section in the view .

User_Controller.php

```
     public function deconnexion() 
   {
     //var_dump('test');die;
     $client = User::Deco();
    require_once('index.php');
  //header('Location:http://index.php');exit;
   }
```

User.php

```
             public static function RecupMDP() 
      {

     if(isset($_GET['section']))
     {
     $section=htmlspecialchars($_GET['section']);
     }
    else
     {

     $section=" ";
     }
    if(isset($_POST['recup_submit']))
   {
    $recup_mail=$_POST['recup_mail'];
    $db = Db::getInstance();
    $mailexist =$db->prepare("SELECT id_user,login FROM users WHERE email = 
   ?");
    $mailexist->execute(array($recup_mail));
    $mailexist_count = $mailexist->rowCount();
    if($mailexist_count==1)
    {
    @session_start();
    $pseudo=$mailexist->fetch();
    $pseudo=$pseudo['login'];

    $_SESSION['recup_mail']=$recup_mail;
    $recup_code="";
    for ($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) 
    { 
     $recup_code.=mt_rand(0,9);

   }
   //$_SESSION['recup_code']=$recup_code;
   $mail_recup_exist=$db->prepare("SELECT id FROM recuperation WHERE mail=?");
   $mail_recup_exist->execute(array($recup_mail));
   $mail_recup_exist=$mail_recup_exist->rowCount();

   if ($mail_recup_exist==1) {
    $recup_insert =$db->prepare("UPDATE recuperation set code = ? WHERE mail = ?");
    $recup_insert->execute(array($recup_code,$recup_mail));

  }
  else
  {
   $recup_insert =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO recuperation(mail,code) VALUES (?,?)");
   $recup_insert->execute(array($recup_mail,$recup_code));

 }


 $header="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header.='From:"PrimFX.com"<slim7040@hotmail.fr>'."\n";
 $header.='Content-Type:text/html; charset="utf-8"'."\n";
 $header.='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';
 $message = '
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Récupération de mot de passe - PrimFX.com</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <font color="#303030";>
     <div align="center">
       <table width="600px">
         <tr>
           <td>

             <div align="center">Bonjour <b>'.$pseudo.'</b>,</div>
             Voici votre code de récupération: <b>'.$recup_code.'</b><br/><br/>
             A bientôt sur <a href="http://127.0.0.1/PROJET_WEB%20-%20Copie/">OpticDeParis.com</a> !

           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td align="center">
             <font size="2">
               Ceci est un email automatique, merci de ne pas y répondre
             </font>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
   </font>
 </body>
 </html>
 ';

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't 
have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

/ /Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
   //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
     $mail->isSMTP();
    //Enable SMTP debugging
   // 0 = off (for production use)
     // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
     //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    //Set the hostname of the mail server
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
  // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
 // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
 //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP 
 submission
$mail->Port = 587;
  //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 //Whether to use SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
 );
 //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for 
   gmail
 $mail->Username = "aouadi.slim96@gmail.com";
 //Password to use for SMTP authentication
  $mail->Password = "trak22683166";
   //Set who the message is to be sent from
   $mail->setFrom('slim.aouadi@esprit.tn', 'Aouadi Slim');
   //Set an alternative reply-to address
   $mail->addReplyTo('slim.aouadi@esprit.tn', 'First Last');
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
  $mail->addAddress($recup_mail);
   //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'Recuperation Mdp ';
   //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced 
images to embedded,
  //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
   //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
   $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    //Attach an image file
     $mail->Body=$message;

   if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } 
   else {
      echo "Message sent!";
     header("Location:http://127.0.0.1/PROJET_WEB%20-%20Copie/?
     controller=user&action=recupmdp&section=code");
       ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href ="?controller=user&action=recupmdp&section=code"
     </script>
    <?php
     }
       //mail($recup_mail,"Récupération de mot de passe - 
      OpticDeParis.com",$message, $header);
    }
     else
    {
      echo "Cette Adresse mail n'existe pas ";
     }

     }
   else

     {
    $error="Veuillez Saisir Votre Adresse Mail ! ";
      }

     }


   }
```

recupmdp.php

```
             <!-- reg-form -->
      <div class="account">
        <div class="account-left">
     <h2>Recuperer votre mot de passe</h2>
        <?php if(isset($section)=='code') { ?>
         Un code de verification vous a été envoyé par mail : <?= 
       $_SESSION['recup_mail']?>
          <br/> <br/>
         <form id="registration_form" method="POST" action="?
        controller=user&action=recupmdp">
           <div>
            <label>
                <input placeholder="Code de vérification" type="text" 
           name="code_code">
            </label>
        </div>                  
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Valider" name="verif_submit" 
        id="register-submit">
        </div>
        <div class="forget">

        </div>
        </form>
          <?php   } elseif(isset($section)=='changemdp'){ ?>
          Nouveau de mot de passe pour <?= $_SESSION['recup_mail']?>
         <br/> <br/>
         <form id="registration_form" method="POST" action="?
        controller=user&action=recupmdp">
        <div>
            <label>
                <input placeholder="Nouveau mot de passe" type="passeword" 
           name="change_mdp">
            </label>
        </div>  
        <div>
            <label>
                <input placeholder="Confirmation mot de passe" 
          type="password" name="change_mdpc">
            </label>
        </div>              
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Recupere" name="change_submit" 
     id="register-submit">
        </div>
        <div class="forget">

        </div>
    </form> 
    <?php } else{ ?>
    <div class="registration_form">
        <!-- Form -->
        <form id="registration_form" method="POST" action="?
         controller=user&action=recupmdp">
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="email" type="email" 
         name="recup_mail">
                </label>
            </div>                  
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Recupere" name="recup_submit" 
         id="register-submit">
            </div>
            <div class="forget">

            </div>
        </form> 
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if(isset($error)){ echo '<span 
       style="color:red">'.$error.'</span>';} else {echo "<br/>";} ?>
            <!-- /Form -->
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: `if(isset($section)=='code')` that isn't a valid method, nor `elseif(isset($section)=='changemdp')`

Comment: yes sorry i was just trying but the tuto that i followed was putting only 
if($section=='code') but didn't work for me like i said